# VScode - print not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Trying to do a couple of simple print statements and I think VScode is coughing up a hairball or I'm missing something. I'm using windows 10.

Example 1: (there are 10 `.jpg` images in this folder)

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
    print(f)
```

Output:

```
[Running] python "C:\img\resize.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.421 seconds
```

My understanding is that this would print out all `.jpg` files in the same directory that the `.py` file is saved.

UPDATE: Exact code formatting

```
import os
from os import listdir

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        print(f)
```

Output:

```
[Running] python "c:\img\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.24 seconds
```

Am I still correct to assume that if there was a .jpg file in the working directory aka the directory the resize.py file is in that it would list them all out?

```
Directory output:
PS C:\img> ls
    Directory: C:\img
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/16/2018  10:14 AM            110 resize.py
-a----       11/11/2017   5:01 PM         177632 Scenery_003.jpg
-a----       11/11/2017   5:01 PM         256268 Scenery_004.jpg
-a----       11/11/2017   5:02 PM         153166 Scenery_005.jpg
-a----        1/16/2018  10:01 AM             88 test.py
```

Think i got it, not how I wanted it but...

```
import os
from os import listdir

for f in os.listdir("c:\\img\\"):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        print(f)
```

Output:

```
[Running] python "c:\img\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Scenery_003.jpg
Scenery_004.jpg
Scenery_005.jpg

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.234 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formating is wrong:

```
    for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        print(f)
```

print(f) has to be shifted right
Except of that, the code works on my machine.

Have you tried the code outside VS-Code?

Comment: Must be something with VScode then cause its shifted right on my end and I still have the same issue as the output completes with Done and no file iteration.

Comment: Have you tried the code outside VS-Code? In your terminal?

Comment: You seen to be using the code runner extension. You might want to try using the python vscode extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and you could run the code without debugging. (Ctrl+f5). There are other ways as well, including 'Python Run Python File in terminal' (you might however warm to configure the working directory under some circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is slightly off: `My understanding is that this would print out all jpg files in the same directory that the .py file is saved.`

The `.`-Folder refers to the current working directory. That may or may not be the directory, the file is in.

There is also the formatting issue [@jfk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285327/1392490) mentions

Comment: Thx for the reply, i updated with some more info above. Exact formatting and list of the files in the directory id expect it to print. Any other thoughts?